# How to pass the Object complex (DTO) into WCF Post method using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I am struggling to pass the complex object with multiple parameters from client side to server side.

Service.cs

```
public UserResponseData GetTestobject(UserRequestDataTest reqData,string strTest)
{
    dynamic response;

    bool IsValidUser = false;

    if (IsValidUser)
    {
        response = new UserResponseData { LoginResult = "Success" };
    }
    else
    {
        response = new UserResponseData { LoginResult = "Invalid username and password" };
    }

    return response;
}
```

IService.cs

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
    Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "GetTestobject/", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
UserResponseData GetTestobject(UserRequestDataTest reqData,string strTest);
```

// DataContract

```
[DataContract]
public class UserRequestDataTest
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<test> objTestList { get; set; }
}


[DataContract]
public class test
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

From Client side to access the service method

```
        Uri address = new Uri("http://localhost:122/Service.svc/web/GetTestobject/");

        // Create the web request  
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(address) as HttpWebRequest;

        // Set type to POST  
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";


        UserRequestDataTest objUserRequestDataTest = new UserRequestDataTest();
        List<test> objtestList = new List<test>();

        test objtest = new test();
        objtest.Address = "1";
        objtest.Name = "1";
        objtestList.Add(objtest); 

        objtest = new test();
        objtest.Address = "1";
        objtest.Name = "1";
        objtestList.Add(objtest);

        objUserRequestDataTest.objTestList = objtestList;
        objUserRequestDataTest.Password = "Test";
        objUserRequestDataTest.Username= "Test";

        var json1 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(objUserRequestDataTest);

        JObject jsonNew = new JObject();
        jsonNew.Add("reqData", json1);
        jsonNew.Add("strTest", "Test");

        string data = jsonNew.ToString();

        // Create a byte array of the data we want to send  
        byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        // Set the content length in the request headers  
        request.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

        // Write data  
        using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
        }

        // Get response  
        using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {
            // Get the response stream  
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }
```

I am getting this error **"The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."** Please guide me to solve the issues

Comment: If you want to use HTTPWebRequest it's easier to use WebApi than WCF.

Comment: could you try to add some GET method with some simple string return value - to validate that the url http://localhost:122/Service.svc/web/ passes where it should pass..?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to consume the service this way: 
[Consuming a WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655893%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

And Then you can use it simple way:

```
var sc = new ServiceReference1.SomeClient();
var st = sc.GetTestobject(objectParameter,"parameter1");
```